# How to log into a browser prompt (Picture below) with a python request?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

[image: Chrome Browser Prompt to Sign in]

First, please recognize there are many answered questions about forum type logins.
This is different, as this prompt does not appear in the HTML or JS.

I'm trying to automate some web scraping.

I would like to use something like the following to log into the page:

```
login_URL = 'https://somewebsite.com'
page_URL = 'https://somewebsite.com'

payload{
    'Username': 'yourusername',
    'Password': 'yourpassword'
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(login_URL, data=payload)
    r = session.get(page_URL)
    print(r.text)
```

Based on my research, this doesn't seem possible since the prompt appears before the page even loads.

Any insights would be helpful!

Comment: This is so oldschool, I personally didn't see that in years, and thus I can only guess that it's probably a browser's response to `401 Unauthorized`... but the image you've posted looks **too custom** to me, so maybe that's a *JS* after all. Add the link to the real site. Without that I doubt that you'll get the answer. But as a wild guess: try `session.get('https://yourusername:yourpassword@somewebsite.com')`. Will it help?

Comment: session.get('https://yourusername:yourpassword@somewebsite.com') was it! That works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments it becomes clear that that was a browser's response to `401 Unauthorized`.
So, to login you need to do this:

```py
session.get('https://yourusername:yourpassword@somewebsite.com')
```